# SSIS transformation Error

Tags: ssis

I have rows with JR or SR in there name column I want them to be at the end I could remove the special characters but confused in this step

```
 NUM           VEH              NAME                 NAME_Clean
 017            1       CLARK, jr WILLIAM            CLARK WILLIAM JR
 037            2       DESORMEAUX, JR. MICHELLE     DESORMEAUX MICHELLE JR
 043            1       FALCON, JENNIFER,jr          FALCON JENNIFER JR
 073            2       WINTERS, ALLEN               WINTERS ALLEN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Derived Column Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141069%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) with an SSIS Expression to replace an embedded " JR " with a trailing " JR":

```
FINDSTRING(NAME, " JR ") > 0 ? REPLACE(NAME, " JR ", "") + " JR" : NAME
```

If you would like to do this for several different strings, you can nest the expressions, or use multiple transformations one after the other.

For more information, see [SSIS Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141671.aspx), [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141196.aspx), [FINDSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141748.aspx), the [Concatenate operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms138036.aspx), and the [Conditional operator (?:)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141680.aspx).

Comment: You're welcome. I see that @user2795707 also posted a similar answer while I was putting together mine (independently), so I'm giving that answer an upvote also.

Answer (score 2):

use a Derived Column transformation and create a new derived column based on NAME column with the following:

(FINDSTRING([NAME],"jr",1)==1||FINDSTRING([NAME],"JR",1)==1)?REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([NAME],",",""),".",""),"JR",""),"jr","")+" JR":REPLACE(REPLACE([NAME],",",""),".","")

note that the first expression FINDSTRING works only with DT_WSTR data type

good luck :)